# ND and D yielding strange results

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Both of the following codes, using ND and D, differentiates my function Flux[] incorrectly. If the derivatives are plotted, it can be seen that both are the original function multiplied by some constant, one positive and the other negative.

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];

mu0=4Pi*10^-7;
r1=0.3;
r2=1;
n=1;
q=1;
q0=10;
m=1;
ro=1;
step=0.1;
l=10^-3;
res=1;
ca=10^-3;
period=2Pi/(4*(1/(l*ca)-(res/(2*l))^2)^(0.5));

I0[t_]=-D[q0*Exp[-t*res/(2*l)]*Cos[(1/(l*ca)-(res/(2*l))^2)^(0.5)*t],t];
B[r_,s_,t_]=(mu0*98/(2Pi*r2))*I0[t]*(1-(r*Sin[s]/r1)^2)^0.5/(2Pi*(r2-r1*Cos[s]));

Flux[r0_?NumericQ,t_?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[B[r,s,t]*r,{s,0,2Pi},{r,0,r0},AccuracyGoal->3,PrecisionGoal->3,Method->"Trapezoidal"];

Show[Plot[q0*Exp[-t*res/(2*l)]*Cos[(1/(l*ca)-(res/(2*l))^2)^(0.5)*t],{t,0,4*period},PlotRange->All,PlotStyle->Green],Plot[q0*Exp[-t*res/(2*l)],{t,0,4*period},PlotRange->All,PlotStyle->{Purple,Dashed}],Plot[-q0*Exp[-t*res/(2*l)],{t,0,4*period},PlotRange->All,PlotStyle->{Purple,Dashed}],Plot[q0*Cos[(1/(l*ca)-(res/(2*l))^2)^(0.5)*t],{t,0,4*period}],AxesLabel->{t,Charge}]
Plot[I0[t],{t,0,4*period},AxesLabel->{t,Current},PlotStyle->Orange]
Plot[Flux[0.2,t],{t,0,4*period},AxesLabel->{t,Flux}]
Plot[D[Flux[0.2,t],t]/.t->t0,{t0,0,4*period},PlotStyle->Red,AxesLabel->{t,Emf}]
period
```

and

```
Plot[ND[Flux[0.2,t],t,t0],{t0,0,4*period},PlotStyle->Red,AxesLabel->{t,Emf}]
```

If I plug in a simple polynomial to B[], plots appear to be correct. I would appreciate if you could spot the mistake for me,

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about explicitly differentiating under the integral sign?

```
dFlux[r0_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][B][r, s, t]*r, {s, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, r0}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3, Method -> "Trapezoidal"];

Plot[Flux[0.2, t], {t, 0, 4*period}, AxesLabel -> {t, Flux}]

Plot[dFlux[0.2, t], {t, 0, 4*period}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 AxesLabel -> {t, Emf}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]